# consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://user:**@rabbit1:5672//: failed to resolve broker hostname

Tags: python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, rabbitmq, celery

I have perused through very similar stackoverflow questions and changed my code to what it is now. I am still getting the `cannot resolve broker hostname` error. If I just use `amqp:user:mypass@locahost:5672` I get the a `connection refused`

```
# docker-compoose.yml
version: "3.8"

services: 
  broker:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbit1
    environment: &env
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "user"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "password"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: "amqp://user:password@rabbit1:5672"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    expose:
      - "5672"
    networks:
      - webnet
    volumes: 
      - .:/home/user

  worker:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./worker/Dockerfile
    command: ["celery", "worker", "--app=worker.tasks.app", "--loglevel=INFO"]
    environment: 
      <<: *env
    links: 
      - broker 
    depends_on: 
      - broker
    networks:
      - webnet
    volumes: 
      - .:/home/user


networks:
    webnet:
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN groupadd user && useradd --create-home --home-dir /home/user -g user user
ENV CELERY_USER = user

WORKDIR /home/user
COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
RUN rm requirements.txt
```

I have tried just starting the rabbitmq broker through docker-compose and then manually doing a `celery worker --app=tasks.app` and that will work after setting the `CELERY_BROKER_URL=amqp://user:mypass@localhost:5672`

It throws the error when I have the worker and broker in the same yaml. I've tried it without the network, manually setting the CELERY_BROKER_URL in the Dockerfile also. If anyone has ideas what I'm doing wrong, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You should be using the hostname "broker" to contact your rabbitmq container (because that's what you've named it).

Comment: it's not named "rabbit1" when I specified it with `hostname: rabbit1` ?

Comment: Okay, I removed `hostname: rabbit1` and used broker instead but I still get the connection refused error.

Comment: Specifying `hostname: rabbit1` is very similar to running `sudo hostname stackoverflow.com` on your local system: it changes an internal notion of what "my hostname" is, but doesn't change how anything else sees it (including other containers).  RabbitMQ is one of the few cases where it's useful to set `hostname:` at all (your `hostname: rabbit1` is just fine).

Comment: Just FYI, exposing ports is unnecessary - services on the same network can access each other's containers on any port

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things going on here. The first, addressed in comments, is that from the perspective of your `worker` container, your rabbitmq service is available on host `broker`, so your `CELERY_BROKER_URL` variable should point at `amqp://user:password@broker:5672`.

The second issue is that rabbitmq takes a while to start up. This means you'll initially see errors from `celery worker` when it first starts up, because it will attempt to connect before rabbitmq is ready. However, it will retry until it is successful.

I was able to get everything to work correctly with the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  broker:
    image: rabbitmq:3-management-alpine
    hostname: rabbit1
    environment: &env
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "SWQOKODSQALRPCLNMEQG"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "user"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "password"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
      CELERY_BROKER_URL: "amqp://user:password@broker:5672"
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    expose:
      - "5672"
    volumes: 
      - .:/home/user

  worker:
    image: celery
    command: ["celery", "worker", "-l" "INFO"]
    environment:
      <<: *env
    volumes:
      - .:/home/user
```

That's very similar to yours, but (a) I'm using the official `celery` image, since you didn't show us your Dockerfile, and (b) I've removed the `links:` key, because `links` has been deprecated in favor of the DNS-based service discovery that is now the default. Oh, and (c) I got rid of the custom network, since if you're creating a single network you might as well just use the default that `docker-compose` creates for you.

When I bring this up, I eventually see:

```
broker_1  | 2020-05-11 21:46:10.098 [info] <0.634.0> connection <0.634.0> (172.26.0.3:39372 -> 172.26.0.2:5672): user 'user' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
broker_1  | 2020-05-11 21:46:10.111 [info] <0.639.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.639.0> (172.26.0.3:39374 -> 172.26.0.2:5672)
worker_1  | [2020-05-11 21:46:10,100: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://user:**@broker:5672//
worker_1  | [2020-05-11 21:46:10,115: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
worker_1  | [2020-05-11 21:46:11,140: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
```

Comment: Ah, I read somewhere that the celery image was deprecated so the Docker I linked with python was just installing celery 4.4.2 on a vanilla python container. I will try using the celery image instead. I had started slapping on the network and links from just trying whatever I could. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you use the `celery` image; I was only using that because it seemed easier than trying to reproduce your image without your `requirements.txt`, etc.

Comment: I misunderstood, thank you very much, I adapted your changes and didn't have to use the celery image. It works! Super appreciate it fam.